# Trying to load some data in

Tags: javascript, html, json, svg

I am trying to understand how to run some code. I would like to have the circles plot with my data from the JSON file. I am not too sure how to go about this. I think I am messing up with not connecting the files or maybe my JSON file isn't set up correctly....my end goal is to make a connected scatterplot so, for now, I am just focusing on the circles.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg id="s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function makeSVG(tag, attrs) {
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (var k in attrs)
      el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    return el;
  }

  var data;
  $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nataliemcg18/Data/master/temp.json", function(data) {
    draw(data);
  });

  var circle = makeSVG('circle', {
    cx: 100,
    cy: 50,
    r: 40,
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    fill: 'red'
  });
  var data
  document.getElementById('s').appendChild(circle);
</script>

<svg width="1000" height="1000">
        <line x1="200" y1="100" x2="200" y2="600" height="1000" width="1000" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2"  /> 
        <line x1="200" y1="600" x2="900" y2="600" height="1000" width="1000" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" /> <!-- bottom line -->
```

```
[
  {"Month": 0, "Temperature": 32},
  {"Month": 1, "Temperature": 43},
  {"Month": 2, "Temperature": 52},
  {"Month": 3, "Temperature": 60},
  {"Month": 4, "Temperature": 70},
  {"Month": 5, "Temperature": 80},
  {"Month": 6, "Temperature": 90},
  {"Month": 7, "Temperature": 80},
  {"Month": 8, "Temperature": 65},
  {"Month": 9, "Temperature": 45},
  {"Month": 10, "Temperature": 33},
  {"Month": 11, "Temperature": 24}
]
```

Comment: The circle drawing is working.  But we can't really help you with the JSON processing without seeing what your JSON looks like.  You are however missing a `draw()` fuinction.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this ?
2 values - zero and max added just for fun... You can still read and pass data from original jQuery request.

```js
// 1 (-2) new functions
function draw(data) {
    var placeHolder = document.getElementById('s');
    const diameter = 25, height = placeHolder.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.y2.baseVal.value - placeHolder.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.y1.baseVal.value;
    setMax(data, height - 2 * diameter); // set last temperature value as chart max
    for(var month in data) {
            var pair = data[month];
            var circle = makeSVG('circle', {
            cx: pair.Month * diameter * 2 + 200 + diameter,
            cy: 600 - diameter - pair.Temperature,
            r: diameter,
            stroke: 'black',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            fill: 'red'
        });
        placeHolder.appendChild(circle);
    }
}

function setMax(data, value) {
    data[data.length-1].Temperature = value;
}

// Your untouched logic
$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nataliemcg18/Data/master/temp.json", function(data) {
    draw(data);
});

function makeSVG(tag, attrs) {
    var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
    for (var k in attrs)
        el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
    return el;
}

var circle = makeSVG('circle', {
    cx: 100,
    cy: 50,
    r: 40,
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    fill: 'red'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1000" height="1000">
    <line x1="200" y1="100" x2="200" y2="600" height="1000" width="1000" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />
    <line x1="200" y1="600" x2="900" y2="600" height="1000" width="1000" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2" />
<svg id="s" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
```